# Can a collection.inject([]){...} return [ ] (empty) if nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following method returns an empty array if there is no result to .where() query. How would this be achieved with an `inject([]){ |memo, value| memo << value }`? By default, `inject([])` returns `nil` if no result is found to `.where()` query.

```
def jobs_it_can_be_contacted_for
 jobs = []
 user_jobs.where("user_jobs.user_job_type IN (?)", ['job', 'represent']).each do |user_job|
  jobs << user_job.job unless user_job.job == Job.unknown
 end
 jobs
end
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `inject` returns `nil` if and only you return `nil` from the block explicitly. For noop (empty `where()` returns an empty relation) is returns the default value of accumulator.

Comment: Any chance to move the filtering operation into the query? How do your tables / relations look like?

Answer (score 3):

This should not be achieved with `inject`, there is [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) for this type of task:

```
user_jobs.
    where("user_jobs.user_job_type IN (?)", ['job', 'represent']).
    each_with_object([]) do |user_job, jobs|
  jobs << user_job.job unless user_job.job == Job.unknown
end
```

FWIW, [`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) implementation:

```
user_jobs.
    where("user_jobs.user_job_type IN (?)", ['job', 'represent']).
    inject([]) do |jobs, user_job|
  user_job.job == Job.unknown ? jobs : jobs << user_job.job
end
```

---

The most succinct one (credits to @Stefan):

```
user_jobs.
    where("user_jobs.user_job_type IN (?)", ['job', 'represent']).
    map(&:job).
    reject { |job| job == Job.unknown }
```

The last line might be also rewritten as:

```
    reject(&Job.unknown.method(:==))
```

Comment: second solution works really fine! Thank you Mudasobwa.

Comment: Something like `where(...).map(&:job).reject { |j| j == Job.unknown }` should work as well (or preferably `reject(&:unknown?)`).

Comment: Second solution **should not be used** since it’s a wrong not idiomatic approach. One should go with the first one. _Correction:_ **one should go with what @Stefan suggested in the comment above**.

Comment: Ok, I'll choose solution one then. What do you mean by 'wrong not idiomatic approach' ?

Comment: @Stefan `reject(&Job.unknown.method(:==))` :)

Comment: The `reject` approach is a lot better than the `each_with_object` one. It's worth moving those solutions to the top.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler option would be to use [`Enumerable#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) instead of `inject` or `each_with_object`. The method is available on all arrays as well as active record relations.

With that, you can simplify you code to

```
def jobs_it_can_be_contacted_for
  user_jobs
    .where("user_jobs.user_job_type IN (?)", ['job', 'represent'])
    .map(&:job)
    .reject { |job| job == Job.unknown }
end
```

To quote the documentation of the `reject` method:

> Returns an array for all elements of `enum` for which the given `block` returns `false`.

Comment: This returns a list of wrong objects, one should `map(&:job)` upfront as @Stefan suggested in the comment to my answer.

Comment: Ah, I missed that OP returns the actual jobs. Yeah, in that case, a `map` followed by a `reject` is probably the best solution. I edited my answer.